# C# Calling a Method Inside another Method

Tags: c#, methods, callback, call, steam

```
public static void Main2(string[] args)
        {
            WebRequest_BeginGetRequeststream.RequestCheck();
            WebRequest_BeginGetRequeststream.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult);
        }
```

This is the Method I want to call.

```
static void OnMsg(SteamFriends.FriendMsgCallback callback)
        {
            string msg = callback.Message;

            //Announcement Related Messages
            if (msg == "RequestCheck") 
            {
                Main2 (string[] args);
                Console.WriteLine("Starting Operation Line for Announcement Creation.");
                Console.WriteLine("Version 1.08 of Announcement Code Initiated.");
            }
}
```

This is where I want to call the method, I had everything else set but I wanted to make it so that inside the...

```
if (msg == "RequestCheck") 
                {
                    Main2 (string[] args);
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting Operation Line for Announcement Creation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Version 1.08 of Announcement Code Initiated.");
                }
```

It can call Main2 which will run the WebRequests, It tells me that I need to make a return type and when I do that, I get a whole bunch of errors.

How can I call inside Method OnMsg and call Main2 without disrupting the Method.

by the way, to get to where I am now. I had been following this code.

```
public class AllMethods
{
    public static void Method2()
    {
        // code here
    }
}

class Caller
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AllMethods.Method2();
    }
}
```

I had seen that this method had works and tried to try it our but I still have problems calling inside OnMsg.

Comment: You appear to be unfamiliar with the syntax for calling methods. You don't specify the parameter types in the method call - just the arguments themselves. So `Main(string[] args)` would actually just be `Main(args)`. If you're very new to C#, I'd *strongly* advise you to write some simple *synchronous* code before you dive into asynchrony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `Main2 (args);` instead, where args is a `string[]`, for example `new string[]{"foo", "bar"}` or `null`. Alternativly, you can implicitly pass specified arguments to the call as an array if you add `params` to the main methods argument `args`: `public static void Main2(params string[] args) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the parameters to the Main2 function, in this case an array of strings.